# AlarmManager doesn't work all the time when app is killed

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I am using AlarmManager in my app. It works all the time when app is in the foreground but doesn't work most of the times when app is killed(But works sometimes).

Below is the code to set the Alarm:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmService.class);
            intent.setAction(AlarmService.ACTION_SHOW_ALERTS);
            intent.putExtra(Constants.BundleKeys.ALERTS_ID,alert.getId());

            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(context, alert.getAlertID(), intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
            AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23)

                alarmManager.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, alert.getId(), pendingIntent);
            else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19)

                alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, alert.getId(), pendingIntent);
            else

                alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, alert.getId(), pendingIntent);
```

My AlarmService.java class:

```
public class AlarmService extends IntentService {

public AlarmService() {
    super("Alarm service");
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
}

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(@Nullable Intent intent) {
    
    Intent alarm = new Intent(this, AlarmActivity.class);
    alarm.putExtra(BundleKeys.ALERTS_ID, alertId);
    alarm.putExtra(BundleKeys.IS_SNOOZED, snoozed);
    alarm.setFlags(FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(alarm);
}}
```

My AlarmActivity, which is shown when alarm reaches the time:

```
public class AlarmActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    // Turn the device's screen on and keep it turned on and bright
    // as long as this window is visible to the user
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON
            | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_alarm);

    Long alertTime = getIntent().getLongExtra(BundleKeys.ALERTS_ID,0);
    boolean isSnoozed = getIntent().getBooleanExtra(BundleKeys.IS_SNOOZED, false);

    Fragment fragment = AlarmFragment.newInstance(alertTime, isSnoozed);
    FragmentUtils.addFragment(this, fragment, R.id.container);

    final Window win = getWindow();
    win.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED
            | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD);
}

//DO not remove this method
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
}}
```

My Manifest:

```
<service android:name="AlarmService"/>

    <activity
        android:name="AlarmActivity"
        android:excludeFromRecents="true"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:showOnLockScreen="true"></activity>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This might help. https://stackoverflow.com/a/64870635/8851971

Comment: I am whitelisting the app. And behavior is similar in most of the devices. I tested in LG, Redmi, Lenovo. @NadeemShaikh